# I cannot solve this with slick2D Java

Tags: java, slick2d

I'm trying to make a splash screen for a game. I've searched Google without avail. I was following this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBQ5t9vHrzA) and it worked for him. My code was a little different but looked a little like his. Here is my code:

**GAME CLASS:**

```
import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;

public class Game extends StateBasedGame {

public static final String gamename = "Life - Alpha";
public static int menu = 1;
public static int play = 2;
public static int splash = 0;

public Game(String gamename) {
    super(gamename);
}

public void initStatesList(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException {
    this.getState(menu).init(gc, this);
    this.getState(play).init(gc, this);
    this.enterState(0);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    AppGameContainer app;
    try {
        app = new AppGameContainer(new Game(gamename));
        app.setDisplayMode(800, 600, false);
        app.start();
    } catch (SlickException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   }
}
```

**MENU CLASS:**

```
import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;

public class Menu extends BasicGameState {

public Menu(int state) {

}

public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException {

}

public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException {

    Image back = new Image("res/Back.png");
    g.drawImage(back, 0, 0);

    Image panel = new Image("res/Panel.png");
    g.drawImage(panel, 240, 100);

    Image logo = new Image("res/Life Alpha.png");
    g.drawImage(logo, 290, 130);

    Image playButton = new Image("res/Play.png");
    g.drawImage(playButton, 330, 310);

    Image exitButton = new Image("res/Exit.png");
    g.drawImage(exitButton, 330, 370);

}

public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException {     

    Input input = gc.getInput();
    int xpos = Mouse.getX();
    int ypos = Mouse.getY();

    if((xpos > 330 && xpos < 480) && (ypos > 250 && ypos < 290)) {
        if(input.isMousePressed(0)) {
            sbg.enterState(2);
        }
    }
}

public int getID() {
    return 0;
}

}
```

**PLAY CLASS:**

```
import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;

public class Play extends BasicGameState {

public Play(int state) {

}

public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException {

}

public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException {

    Image back = new Image("res/Back.png");
    g.drawImage(back, 0, 0);

    Image panel = new Image("res/Panel2.png");
    g.drawImage(panel, 170, 100);

}

public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException {

}

public int getID() {
    return 1;
}

}
```

**SPLASHSCREEN CLASS:**

```
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.BasicGameState;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

public class SplashScreen extends BasicGameState {

Image splash;

private int elapsedTime;
private final int DELAY = 3000;

public SplashScreen(int state) {

}

public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException {

    splash = new Image("res/SplashScreen.png");

}

public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException {

    g.drawImage(splash, 0, 0);

}

public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException {

    elapsedTime += delta;

    if(elapsedTime >= DELAY) {

        sbg.enterState(1);

    }

}

public int getID() {
    return 0;
}

}
```

The error i get is:

Sat Apr 27 22:48:01 EST 2013 INFO:Slick Build #274

Sat Apr 27 22:48:01 EST 2013 INFO:LWJGL Version: 2.8.5

Sat Apr 27 22:48:01 EST 2013 INFO:OriginalDisplayMode: 1366 x 768 x 32 @60Hz

Sat Apr 27 22:48:01 EST 2013 INFO:TargetDisplayMode: 800 x 600 x 0 @0Hz

Sat Apr 27 22:48:01 EST 2013 INFO:Starting display 800x600

Sat Apr 27 22:48:01 EST 2013 INFO:Use Java PNG Loader = true

Sat Apr 27 22:48:01 EST 2013 INFO:Controllers not available

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

at mms001.Game.initStatesList(Game.java:18)

at org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame.init(StateBasedGame.java:164)

at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.setup(AppGameContainer.java:390)

at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:314)

at mms001.Game.main(Game.java:29)

Comment: Use a [`SplashScreen`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) instead.

Comment: oops... i found some mistakes in my code. i fixed it, but now after the `splash screen` finishes showing, it goes to the `play` state, not the `menu`. i don't know what is wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there might be a couple of issues here.

I noticed that your `Menu` class is returning 0 as it's ID and so is the `SplashScreen` class. I bet if you changed the `getID` of the `Menu` class to be 1, that would fix part of your problem.

```
class Menu...
public int getID() {
    return 1;
}
```

You will also need to update your Play class's getID method as well to return 2.

```
class Play...
public int getID() {
    return 2;
}
```

Once you do that they will match your static fields defined in your main class.

Then update your `initStatesList` method to init `splash` and enter the `menu` state

```
public void initStatesList(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException {
    this.getState(splash).init(gc, this);
    this.getState(menu).init(gc, this);
    this.getState(play).init(gc, this);

    this.enterState(menu);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank u! it worked! i just had to change the menu getID() to return 1, and play getID() to return 2; Thank u!